# How to allow airplay with Bluetooth for AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, xcode, avplayer

I have an app which is using AVPlayer. It can cast video to apple TV by Airplay when they are in the same network, but if I set apple TV and iphone in different network, the airplay via bluetooth doesn't work well. The screen will flash once and play on local device. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Airplay works via IP, not Bluetooth.  It also requires multicast routing between networks.  What router are you using?

Comment: You mean Airplay doesn't support Bluetooth? Actually, I create two subnet works eg: 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24

Comment: No, Airplay uses tcp/ip. Bluetooth has its own profile for audio streaming; A2DP, which iOS supports, but this is an open standard. You will need a router that supports multicast forwarding to get Airplay to work across subsets; it is really on,yndesigned for use in home networks with a single subnet. Enterprise wifi systems from vendors such as Cisco have special functions specifically to support airplay in complex environments

Comment: hi @Paulw11, thanks, but I think it's not network issue. I have tried youtube app with same environment and it plays well. For my app, the airplay failed.